# How to hyperlink a span that contains an image

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
    <footer>
    <div class="foot">
    <ul>
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" class="social"><span class="facebook"></span></a>
            <a href="instagram" class="social"><span class="instagram"></span></a>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </footer>
```

CSS:

```
    .facebook {
    display:block;
    background-image:url("../images/facebook.png");
    height:64px;
    width:64px;
}

.instagram {
    display:block;
    background-image:url("../images/instagram.png");
    height:64px;
    width:64px;
}

.social {
    height:64px;
    width:64px;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
}

footer {
    height:75px;
    width:inherit;
    bottom:0;
    position:fixed;
}

.foot {
    text-align:center;
}
```

The way I'm going about it could possibly be the wrong way. Any direction/advice would be great. I've tried using z-index and other properties but just nothing is working. I kinda wonder if it has to do with positioning/display inline.

Comment: \What is not working here?

Comment: The images are not hyperlinked when trying to click on them.

Comment: **Your HTML is invalid to start with**...each of those links should be inside an `li`

Comment: You can add a border around the image via the border CSS rule:

.instagram {
    ...
    border: 1px solid blue;
    background-image:url("Upload/house.jpg");
    ...
}

Comment: What you are doing should work, but it's not valid to have anchors directly inside a `ul` like that. Make sure to wrap each in a `li`.

Comment: They're linked when I try it: http://devdoodle.net/dev/168/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The links worked for me with no trouble.
You don't even need the `span`. You can move the class to the `<a` and have either 2 (social & facebook), or just make it to one css each with the inline and margin.

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/" class="social facebook"></a>
<a href="instagram" class="social instagram"></a>
```

Comment: You sure it's not something else that makes the problem? Other parts of the site?

Comment: It currently works, thank you very much. It was having the position to absolute rather than fixed which was causing the errors.

Answer (score 4):

A `<span>` should not contain any `display:block` elements anyway, it was designed for inline content although you can use it your way. Try use the `<img>` tag instead.
And wrap all your lines inside `li`s because you are using an `ul`

Comment: ...or swap out the `ul` for ` nav`.

Comment: footer class="foot"... too ?

Answer (score 1):

A `span` can have `display:block` property, but why you add span if you have your link ? I cleaned up your html : 
HTML

```
<footer class="foot">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" class="social social-facebook"></a></li>
        <li><a href="instagram" class="social social-instagram"></a></li>
    </ul>
</footer>
```

and CSS

```
.social-facebook {
    background-image:url("../images/facebook.png");
}

.social-instagram {
    background-image:url("../images/instagram.png");
}

.social {
    height:64px;
    width:64px;
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.foot {
    height:75px;
    width:inherit;
    bottom:0;
    position:fixed;
    text-align:center;
}
```

I removed properties repetition and add a little bit of OOCSS :)